# Add Completion handler to a function swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this block of code, which runs an audio file in Swift.

```
 func playSound(name: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "m4a") else {return}
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

                guard let player = self.player else { return }
                player.play()
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to add a completion handler to this block of code. How do I do this?

Comment: You have to answer these questions: what parameters does your completionHandler take? At which point of your function do you want to call it? What do you want to pass to your completionHandler?

Comment: Another thought is do you need a completion handler? Is there a delegate method associated with `AVAudioPlayer` that would get the job done?

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `@escaping` parameter to the declaration, and run the completion closure anywhere you want (most often on success):

```
func playSound(name: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {  // <- HERE
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "m4a") else {return}
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            guard let player = self.player else { return }
            player.play()

            completion()  // <- HERE
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
let audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
audioPlayer.playSound(name: "some_sound") {
    // Completion closure here gets run (given correct input)
    print("Done!")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift, Closure expression syntax has the following general form:

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

You can pass closure as any other variables, the syntax is:

```
closureVarName: (arg1: Type, arg2: Type,....) -> ReturnType
```

So in your case depending on a variables you may want to pass it can be something like this (no arguments):

```
func playSound(name: String, onComplete: @escaping() -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "m4a") else {return}
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

                guard let player = self.player else { return }
                player.play()

                onComplete() // Here you are invoking the closure
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

To pass an argument you just specify it:

```
func playSound(name: String, onComplete: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "m4a") else {return}
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

                guard let player = self.player else { 
                   onComplete(NSError(domain: "Player not found!", code: -1, userInfo: nil)) // Here you are invoking the closure with error variable
                   return 
                }
                player.play()

                onComplete(nil) // Here you are invoking the closure with no error
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                onComplete(error) // Here you pass the error that has caused the exception
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. Notice @escaping flag for the closure variable. It means the closure "escapes" the function that it is called from. This is the case for functions that have async calls in their body (like your function calls DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async that returns immediately so the playSound function will return immediately as well, but the closure will be called at some time later on).

Answer (score 0):

This will add a handler for your code, a boolean and optional error.

```
 func playSound(name: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "m4a") else {return}
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            guard let player = self.player else { return }
            player.play()
            completionHandler(true, nil)

        } catch let error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(false, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: `Result` would work much better here, rather than `(Bool, Error?)`.

Comment: I get what are saying but I just making a point for  @AryanKashyap to know how can it be done with params since the question was really general and didn't have clue for what property and what he really wanted to achieve.